# Linear regression prediction predicting input data (test data), and not test results

Tags: python, statistics, scikit-learn, statsmodels, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to ***predict*** the following:

- `list( [` **`close price (current day)`** - **`open price (current day)`** `] )`

by using the following as input:

- `list( [` **`open price (current day)`** - **`close price (yesterday)`** `] )`

---

However, my `test_prediction` result is a prediction of the incorrect thing.

Predictions from both the `sklearn` and `statsmodels` linear regression models show ~100% correlation between input data (`test_data`) and `prediction results`, whereas the `prediction results` should be correlated to `test_result`.

**What am I doing wrong (or missing here), and how do I fix it?**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
*Code will generate 4 plots showing correlations between different lists.*

---

```
###### Working usable example and code below ######

import numpy as np
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.graph_objs as go

from sklearn import linear_model
import statsmodels.api as sm

def xy_corr( x, y, fname ):
    trace1 = go.Scatter( x          = x, 
                         y          = y, 
                         mode       = 'markers',
                         marker     = dict( size  = 6,
                                            color = 'black',
                                            ),
                         showlegend = False
                         )
    layout = go.Layout( title  = fname )

    fig    = go.Figure( data   = [trace1],
                        layout = layout
                        )
    plot( fig, filename = fname + '.html' )

open_p  = [23215, 23659, 23770, 23659, 23659, 23993, 23987, 23935, 24380, 24271, 24314, 24018, 23928, 23240, 24193, 23708, 23525, 23640, 23494, 23333, 23451, 23395, 23395, 23925, 23936, 24036, 24008, 24248, 24249, 24599, 24683, 24708, 24510, 24483, 24570, 24946, 25008, 24880, 24478, 24421, 24630, 24540, 24823, 25090, 24610, 24866, 24578, 24686, 24465, 24225, 24526, 24645, 24780, 24538, 24895, 24921, 24743, 25163, 25163, 25316, 25320, 25158, 25375, 25430, 25466, 25231, 25103, 25138, 25138, 25496, 25502, 25610, 25625, 25810, 25789, 25533, 25785, 25698, 25373, 25558, 25594, 25026, 24630, 24509, 24535, 24205, 24465, 23847, 24165, 23840, 24216, 24355, 24158, 23203, 23285, 23423, 23786, 23729, 23944, 23637]
close_p = [23656, 23758, 23663, 23659, 23989, 23978, 24142, 24152, 24279, 24271, 24393, 23942, 23640, 24102, 23710, 23708, 23705, 23693, 23561, 23441, 23395, 23395, 23990, 23900, 24158, 24188, 24241, 24248, 24699, 24678, 24715, 24523, 24486, 24483, 24947, 24904, 24923, 24478, 24434, 24421, 24409, 24705, 25047, 24642, 24875, 24866, 24698, 24463, 24262, 24396, 24633, 24645, 24528, 24895, 24895, 24839, 25178, 25163, 25315, 25323, 25149, 25387, 25375, 25469, 25231, 25073, 25138, 25138, 25448, 25611, 25705, 25623, 25813, 25798, 25560, 25518, 25743, 25305, 25654, 25579, 25315, 24783, 24508, 24532, 24208, 24176, 24047, 24148, 24165, 24159, 24286, 24249, 23635, 23128, 23438, 23869, 23420, 23756, 23705, 24018]

open_prev_close_diff    = np.array( [ open_p[i] - close_p[i-1] for i in range( 1, len( open_p ) )] )[np.newaxis].T
open_current_close_diff = np.array( [close_p[i] -  open_p[i]   for i in range( 1, len( open_p ) )] )

train_data = open_prev_close_diff[  :80]
test_data  = open_prev_close_diff[80:]

train_result = open_current_close_diff[  :80]
test_result  = open_current_close_diff[80:]

regressor    = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regressor.fit( train_data, train_result )

test_prediction = np.array( [int(i) for i in regressor.predict( test_data )] )

xy_corr( [int(i) for i in test_result], test_prediction, 'known_result_and_prediction_result_sklearn')
xy_corr( [int(i) for i in test_data],   test_prediction, 'input_data_and_prediction_result_sklearn'  )

olsmod = sm.OLS( train_result, train_data )
olsres = olsmod.fit()

test_prediction = np.array( [int(i) for i in olsres.predict( test_data )] )

xy_corr( [int(i) for i in test_result], test_prediction, 'known_result_and_prediction_result_smOLS')
xy_corr( [int(i) for i in test_data],   test_prediction, 'input_data_and_prediction_result_smOLS'  )
```

Comment: would you mind posting links to your quad of graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <sub>With a hope no one would consider this impolite and/or harmfull,</sub>
> let me cite a lovely point of view on the underlying assumption from “[Correlation **does not imply Causation**](http://www.quantumforquants.org/question/can-clique-analysis-tell-us-something-new-about-time-series/)“: that many contemporary Quantitative Finance modellers **neglect** or **abstract from**:

**For any two correlated events,** **`A`** and **`B`**,
the following relationships are possible:
`A` causes `B`; ( **direct** causation )
`B` causes `A`; ( **reverse** causation )
`A` and `B` are consequences of a **common cause**, but do not cause each other;
`A` causes `B` and `B` causes `A` ( **bidirectional or cyclic** causation );
`A` causes `C` which causes `B` ( **indirect** causation );
There is no connection between `A` and `B`; the correlation is a [**coincidence**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coincidence).

Thus **there can be no conclusion made** regarding the **existence** or the **direction** of a cause-and-effect relationship **only from the fact** that **`A`** and **`B`** are **correlated.**

---

### UPDATE:

There ought be little to no surprise, that a **`LinearRegressor()`** did not produce anything other but a line -- i.e. that each of it's predictions is indeed on the very line of the model. So, half of the plots is **clearly a must-do** for this kind of predictor.
**`Q.E.D.`**

The other half does not show anything else but the level of over-simplification the linear model has employed **in spite of** the observable reality.

Sure, the real behaviour experienced is **NOT** linear ( but do not blame the predictor to "**fail to fit**", it was it's duty to formulate a **`MSE`**-minimiser driven linear model, it could not find any better linear fit on the training part of the `DataSET` and if it were trained over an **`y = x^2`** synthetic `DataSET`  <sub>( **for which one has an a-priori knowledge of the parabolic shape** )</sub> , **again** it will only produce a linear model, with a minimum **`MSE`** over the training-part fraction of the `DataSET` and **we are all sure pretty in advance, that ANY line will thus yield totally flawed** predictions **`OoS`**, but NOT due to it's failure to work well, but due to a principal nonsense in the externally indoctrinated attempt to use a linear-model predictor in a ( knowingly quadratic ) context, where it does not follow the ( known ) reality ).

---

### DataSET:

as an elementary quantitative view, much simpler than a rigorous **`Kolmogorov-Smirnov`** test, for the un-expressed hypothesis,
**check** the percentage fraction of negative difference in intra-day gap `( Open[i] - Close[i-1] )` **`[ 75% ]` from a rather shallow `DataSET` of just 100 samples**
against
a negative difference of the day candle body  `( Close[i] - Open[i] )` with just **`[ 55% ]`** from a rather shallow `DataSET` of 100 samples

Anyway, training as few as 80 day-samples has a poor **chance to generalise well** even on much better engineered predictor-model and ought to focus not only on a better generalisation ability, but also on avoiding seasonal biases et al.

> To have some idea where the ML goes into this field, my best preforming AI/ML-models have about **`0k3`** features ( many of 'em highly non-linear synthetic features ) and get intensively trained accross **`30k+ DataSETs`** with carefully carving out their risk to overfitting and searching vast space of the learner-engines' hyperparameter **`StateSPACE`**

```
|
|>>> QuantFX.get_LDF_GDF_fromGivenRANGE( [ open_PRICE[i] - close_PRICE[i-1] for i in range( 1, len( close_PRICE ) ) ], nBINs_ = 31, aPrefixTEXT_ = "" )
     0:  ~ -432.00 LDF =      1 |____ 1.0 % _||____ 1 %
     1:  ~ -408.10 LDF =      1 |____ 1.0 % _||____ 2 %
     2:  ~ -384.19 LDF =      1 |____ 1.0 % _||____ 3 %
     3:  ~ -360.29 LDF =      0 |____ 0.0 % _||____ 3 %
     4:  ~ -336.39 LDF =      1 |____ 1.0 % _||____ 4 %
     5:  ~ -312.48 LDF =      1 |____ 1.0 % _||____ 5 %
     6:  ~ -288.58 LDF =      1 |____ 1.0 % _||____ 6 %
     7:  ~ -264.68 LDF =      0 |____ 0.0 % _||____ 6 %
     8:  ~ -240.77 LDF =      1 |____ 1.0 % _||____ 7 %
     9:  ~ -216.87 LDF =      3 |____ 3.0 % _||___ 10 %
    10:  ~ -192.97 LDF =      2 |____ 2.0 % _||___ 12 %
    11:  ~ -169.06 LDF =      1 |____ 1.0 % _||___ 13 %
    12:  ~ -145.16 LDF =      1 |____ 1.0 % _||___ 14 %
    13:  ~ -121.26 LDF =      2 |____ 2.0 % _||___ 16 %
    14:  ~  -97.35 LDF =      5 |____ 5.1 % _||___ 21 %
    15:  ~  -73.45 LDF =      3 |____ 3.0 % _||___ 24 %
    16:  ~  -49.55 LDF =      5 |____ 5.1 % _||___ 29 %
    17:  ~  -25.65 LDF =     18 |___ 18.2 % _||___ 47 %
    18:  ~   -1.74 LDF =     28 |___ 28.3 % _||___ 75 %
    19:  ~   22.16 LDF =      5 |____ 5.1 % _||___ 80 %
    20:  ~   46.06 LDF =      5 |____ 5.1 % _||___ 85 %
    21:  ~   69.97 LDF =      2 |____ 2.0 % _||___ 87 %
    22:  ~   93.87 LDF =      1 |____ 1.0 % _||___ 88 %
    23:  ~  117.77 LDF =      4 |____ 4.0 % _||___ 92 %
    24:  ~  141.68 LDF =      1 |____ 1.0 % _||___ 93 %
    25:  ~  165.58 LDF =      1 |____ 1.0 % _||___ 94 %
    26:  ~  189.48 LDF =      1 |____ 1.0 % _||___ 95 %
    27:  ~  213.39 LDF =      1 |____ 1.0 % _||___ 96 %
    28:  ~  237.29 LDF =      0 |____ 0.0 % _||___ 96 %
    29:  ~  261.19 LDF =      1 |____ 1.0 % _||___ 97 %
    30:  ~  285.10 LDF =      2 |____ 2.0 % _||__ 100 %
+0:00:06.234000
|
|
|>>> QuantFX.get_LDF_GDF_fromGivenRANGE( [ close_PRICE[i] - open_PRICE[i] for i in range( 1, len( close_PRICE ) ) ], nBINs_ = 31, aPrefixTEXT_ = "" )
     0:  ~ -523.00 LDF =      2 |____ 2.0 % _||____ 2 %
     1:  ~ -478.32 LDF =      1 |____ 1.0 % _||____ 3 %
     2:  ~ -433.65 LDF =      3 |____ 3.0 % _||____ 6 %
     3:  ~ -388.97 LDF =      1 |____ 1.0 % _||____ 7 %
     4:  ~ -344.29 LDF =      1 |____ 1.0 % _||____ 8 %
     5:  ~ -299.61 LDF =      2 |____ 2.0 % _||___ 10 %
     6:  ~ -254.94 LDF =      7 |____ 7.1 % _||___ 17 %
     7:  ~ -210.26 LDF =      3 |____ 3.0 % _||___ 20 %
     8:  ~ -165.58 LDF =      2 |____ 2.0 % _||___ 22 %
     9:  ~ -120.90 LDF =      5 |____ 5.1 % _||___ 27 %
    10:  ~  -76.23 LDF =      6 |____ 6.1 % _||___ 33 %
    11:  ~  -31.55 LDF =     22 |___ 22.2 % _||___ 55 %
    12:  ~   13.13 LDF =      7 |____ 7.1 % _||___ 62 %
    13:  ~   57.81 LDF =      5 |____ 5.1 % _||___ 67 %
    14:  ~  102.48 LDF =      4 |____ 4.0 % _||___ 71 %
    15:  ~  147.16 LDF =      8 |____ 8.1 % _||___ 79 %
    16:  ~  191.84 LDF =      6 |____ 6.1 % _||___ 85 %
    17:  ~  236.52 LDF =      2 |____ 2.0 % _||___ 87 %
    18:  ~  281.19 LDF =      3 |____ 3.0 % _||___ 90 %
    19:  ~  325.87 LDF =      2 |____ 2.0 % _||___ 92 %
    20:  ~  370.55 LDF =      2 |____ 2.0 % _||___ 94 %
    21:  ~  415.23 LDF =      3 |____ 3.0 % _||___ 97 %
    22:  ~  459.90 LDF =      0 |____ 0.0 % _||___ 97 %
    23:  ~  504.58 LDF =      0 |____ 0.0 % _||___ 97 %
    24:  ~  549.26 LDF =      0 |____ 0.0 % _||___ 97 %
    25:  ~  593.94 LDF =      1 |____ 1.0 % _||___ 98 %
    26:  ~  638.61 LDF =      0 |____ 0.0 % _||___ 98 %
    27:  ~  683.29 LDF =      0 |____ 0.0 % _||___ 98 %
    28:  ~  727.97 LDF =      0 |____ 0.0 % _||___ 98 %
    29:  ~  772.65 LDF =      0 |____ 0.0 % _||___ 98 %
    30:  ~  817.32 LDF =      1 |____ 1.0 % _||__ 100 %
+0:01:13.172000
```

Comment: Totally agreed, but with that said, even with a correlation or not, this seems to be a problem with the code/prediction itself. Let me explain; based on a training and testing data set, one would expect the result from an OLS model to be either one of 2 thing (and correct me if I'm wrong): 1. The predicted result from a training set being close to that of the test result (good fit), or 2. The predicted result from a training set being far off from that of the test result (bad fit). How is it that my predicted result is almost identical to that of the training data?